# How to add attributes to a GCP cloud scheduler job?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-scheduler

I created a cloud scheduler job named "my_job", sending messages every minute to a topic "my_topic" which is running like i expected. Now i would like to add some attributes to my message in order to retrieve them with a cloud function. That is why i executed this command line: 
`gcloud scheduler jobs update pubsub my_job --update-attributes=["name"="test","limit"="1000"]`

Independently,I also tried to create the job directly with this command line: 
`gcloud beta scheduler jobs create pubsub my_job_2 --schedule "*/1 * * * *" --topic my_topic --message-body="Hello" --attributes name=test,limit=1000`

In both cases the console returns :
[image]

But I do not have any network connectivity issues.
My IAM role is project owner.

Any idea ?

Comment: Did you tried to run other commands for example "gcloud compute instances list"? Do you use installed SDK on your computer or browser version?

Comment: This command line works. And i use browser version.

Comment: And if you try to run "gcloud scheduler jobs create" right after you are getting network message?

Comment: It works. Do you think it was just a temporary problem? Can you post it so that i would be able to accept it has an answer :) Thank you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This indicates a (temporary) network/handshake error from your computer to the data center or on Google's side. Usually, when commands worked before, it will disappear in a few minutes. You could try another command, that should retrieve some results, to see whether the issue is persistent.

```
gcloud scheduler jobs list
```

Another way of testing for connectivity issues is by running the SDK's diagnostics test:

```
gcloud info --run-diagnostics

Network diagnostic detects and fixes local network connection issues.
Checking network connection...done.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
Reachability Check passed.
Network diagnostic passed (1/1 checks passed).

Property diagnostic detects issues that may be caused by properties.
Checking hidden properties...done.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
Hidden Property Check passed.
Property diagnostic passed (1/1 checks passed).
```

Otherwise, if the problem persists, it could also mean that one of Google's services (in a particular region) is unavailable. To check this Google invited a nice [status board](https://status.cloud.google.com/) for all their services.

Answer (score 0):

It's temporary glich and all you need is check the internet connection and try command again also as was mentioned above you can check Google Cloud Services status board. Glad to hear that the issue was resolved.